# access vba add excel button with vba macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to automate the creation of new Excel documents from Access for users so I don't have to manually create them each time.

I have created a button in Excel from Access VBA but now I would like to create a macro which has Excel VBA behind it.

Is this possible?

Comment: so are you trying to create the macro in excel? if so you can follow the resource: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Automate-tasks-with-the-Macro-Recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b

Comment: i want to create the excel macro in access and push it to excel if that makes sense?

Comment: can you map out what steps you want to achieve please, theres not enough information here.

Comment: Curious, what does this button do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate Excel Spreadsheet with Macros using Microsoft Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931178/generate-excel-spreadsheet-with-macros-using-microsoft-access)

Answer (score 1):

You could setup an excel template. When you click the button open it, all your vba code will be in the template (if any) and it will function like normal.